# Doctrine PHPCR @Children & @Child

Tags: doctrine, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

I started learning PHPCR with doctrine in Symfony-CMF, and I have a question.
Is that possible to have @Children and @Child on 2 differents attributes of the same document ?

According to the doc...

> The annotated instance variable will be populated with Documents directly below the instance variables document class in the document hierarchy.

I think that there should be only one @Children or @Child per document. But how to manage forms if there's different documents into the same attribute ? It's not clear for me the usage of this. Should I choose one attribute whith @Children & @ReferenceOne / @ReferenceMany on the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPCR is a tree, every node is located under its parent. For the parent, that is a child node. When using @Child, you adress one specific child with a field. Using @Children, you map *all* child documents and the member variable having this mapping contains a collection. note that there is a middle ground: you can specify to filter @Children by a naming pattern of the children.

indeed you can end up with the same child in @Child and @Children - we recommend to not inline the editing of an unfiltered children collection, but make that links. if you have a filtered children collection and a separate child, things can work out nicely.

references are cross-links not following the tree hierarchy. they are less efficient than parent-child relations. you should only use those for secondary relations, but keep your primary content structured in the tree.

Comment: So, for example, if I've got "media" (collection of media) and "seoMetadata" (from cmf), I have to map both in the same attribute with @Children ? Even if that's not the same document ?

Comment: you can .. or you can use a filter to separate them etc. one of the big advantages of PHPCR is that the structure is not as rigid as with the ORM so you can in fact have collections of mixed types.

Comment: The filter is apply on the attribute which is map @NodeName ? Or on the document name (the php class) ? So if I understand, with filters I can use different attributes to describe child/children ?

Comment: I found the answer, it works with filtering on NodeName attribute :) Thank you very much.